# How to fetch default value in input using angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs

Hi all How to get default value in input using angular js?

- [my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QSniQtwg6NKRCLnAHrFU?p=preview) please look at my plunker I want to fetch `directquestion` values are defaults in an input field.
- `"directquestion": "582c1f4b53cf7fec2ddf282e",` i am expecting to fetch `directquestion` values defaulty in above input field...
- if we fetch that ng-model values in an input field, the data's are got a filter.
- I want to filter `direct question` values through the input field....
- if anyone knows the solution please help me thanks in advance...

Comment: Please explain your problem more accurately.

Comment: i just want to fetch (or) set `directquestion` value default in `input field`....

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant code.  While external links/demos are nice, they are no substitute for actual code in your question.  See also, what is a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to select the first result by default?
If that's what you want, try the following

**UPDATE: I had worn ng-change instead of ng-init**

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="question in questions | filter:directquestion" class="col-md-6" ng-init="selectDirectQuestion($first, question)">
```

CONTROLLER:

```
$scope.selectDirectQuestion = function(first, question){
 if(first){
  $scope.directquestion = question.directquestion;
 }
}
```

If it is the first round of ngRepeat, the value will be assigned to the input model

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q4STCgQcsO3W8lP3VvRE?p=preview)

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer if possible can you update my plunker as well to know the exact solution

Answer (score 0):

You can assign to your `directquestion` the initial value from array.

So you can do this:

```
$scope.directquestion = $scope.questions[0].directquestion;
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer if possible can you update my plunker as well to know the exact solution